# Is there a browser based IDE for Python like RStudio server for R?

Tags: python, rstudio-server

I am familiar with the RStudio server and it is a great tool for R statistical development in remote linux environment.

Just being curious if there is a similar server side IDE for Python development (web browser based)?

Comment: Jupyter notebook. You can also install R. https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r

Comment: There is the paid Python Anywhere, also free Cloud9 account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jupyterlab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) is due to release it's beta release in 31 Dec. 2017, it should be the most similar to RStudio server and probably the most advanced browser based IDE for Python

EDIT:
According to their Github page, it is now out of beta and ready for users.

EDIT 2:
According to their Github page, it is already stable for general use.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) IDE, a free and open-source scientific environment written in Python.

Comment: Link does not work anymore.